# Google Maps launch itinerary with multiple waypoints offline

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on an Android application and I need to launch a road itinerary with multiple waypoints from my application toward google maps.
Right now, I'm able to launch an itinerary with only one waypoint, sending the following URI to Google maps : google.navigation:q=Lat, Lon
But I can't find a way to add multiple waypoints to the itinerary.
Furthermore, my application need to be able to work offline so I can't use the API with URI starting like : http://maps.google.com.

Comment: Please review [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We've tried to put multiple lat and lon one after another separated with semi colons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps Navigation launched via an `Intent` does not support multiple waypoints, only a single destination while using your current location as the starting point:

- `google.navigation:q=`a+street+address
- `google.navigation:q=`latitude,longitude

> q: Sets the end point for navigation searches. This can be a latitude,longitude or a query formatted address. If it is a query string that returns more than one result, the first result will be selected.

re: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents

Comment: Thank you ! ,<br/>Do you know a way of doing it other than with an Intent (even if not with google maps) ?

Comment: @DofMan Due to your offline requirement, the choices lean toward 3rd-party paid SDKs; MapBox, Nutiteq, etc... You can also look at `OpenStreetMap`...  A web search will led you to dozens of options....